# MOSTRAR EN PANTALLA RESULTADO - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql

Supongo que esto es muy básico pero soy nuevo en esto de PL/SQL.
Estoy intentando que me devuelva por pantalla el resultado de la esta función pero no me devuelve nada.
La función es la siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generarUsuario(NUMERO NUMBER,LONGITUD NUMBER,RELLENO CHAR,SUFIJO VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
    retorno varchar2(200);
    operacion_no_permitida EXCEPTION;
    aux varchar2(100) := LENGTH(TO_CHAR(NUMERO));
    sumvals varchar2(100) := aux;
    err_msg varchar(200);
    BEGIN
        IF (LONGITUD <= 15) THEN
            retorno := 'La llamada a la función con Numero='
                        || TO_CHAR(NUMERO)
                        || ', Longitud='
                        || TO_CHAR(LONGITUD)
                        || ', Relleno='
                        || RELLENO
                        || 'y Sufijo='
                        || SUFIJO
                        || ', devolvería='
                        || sumvals;
        ELSE
            RAISE operacion_no_permitida;
            retorno := 'ERRORRRRRRR';
            dbms_output.put_line(retorno);
        END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN operacion_no_permitida THEN
            err_msg := 'La longitud'
                        || Longitud
                        || ' debe ser igual o menor a 15.';
            dbms_output.put_line(err_msg);
        return retorno;
    END;
/
```

Ejecuto la función del a siguiente manera pero no me devuelve nada por pantalla :S

```
DECLARE
    v_resultado VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    v_resultado := generarUsuario(12345, 10, '#', 'ID');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Resultado:' || v_resultado);
END;
/
```

A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano. Gracias de ante mano !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecuta esto en la primera línea antes de ejecutar nada:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Este código redirige los mensajes en el buffer de mensajes DBMS_OUTPUT a la salida estándar. Tal y como se indica en la [documentación de IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-set-serveroutput).

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias !!!